Set the Content Type of Blob using Imperative Binding
I'm trying to set the content type of an output blob to 'text/json' using imperative binding. I'm writing some Azure functions that respond to a service bus trigger by writing some data to a blob, and I need to manually define a filename for my blob output, so I've used imperative binding like so:
[FunctionName("Usage")]
        public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("Usage", "UsageFuncProc", Connection = "UsageFunctionsServiceBus")]ServiceBusReceivedMessage sbusMessage,
            Binder binder)
        {
         ...

         var attributes = new Attribute[]{
                new BlobAttribute($"{Utilities.GetContainerName("BlobContainerName")}/{distFormatted}{timestamp}_{entity.ClientId}_{entity.MessageType}.json", FileAccess.Write),
                new StorageAccountAttribute("AzureWebJobsStorage")
            };

            using (var writer = await binder.BindAsync<TextWriter>(attributes)){
                await writer.WriteAsync(jsonEntity);
            }

This works, but by default it saves the content type as 'application/octet-stream' - How do I change the content type to 'text/json' using imperative binding?

Try this
        var attributes = new Attribute[]{
        new BlobAttribute($"{containerName}/{distFormatted}{timestamp}_{clientId}_{messageType}.json")
        {
            Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage",
            ContentType = "text/json" // Setting the content type to 'text/json'
        }
    }


This does not work because ContentType is not a settable property of BlobAttribute (see doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.webjobs.blobattribute?view=azure-dotnet)
